# Are texture3D lookups with a sampler3D texture available in iOS and OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to call *texture3D(sampler3DTexture, coordinates)* in fragment shader code running OpenGLES 2.0 and iOS?  I know that sampler3D textures aren't explicitly mentioned in OpenGLES but they are included in the in the OpenGLES 2.0 header files from Kronos.

I'm trying to pass a 3D texture into a shader and have it perform a 3D texture lookup in iOS and OpenGLES 2.0.  Any insight?

Comment: A similar question: [How can I use a 3-D texture in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241583/how-can-i-use-3d-texture-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

It's not available in OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification. It's available in 3.0.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, texture3D in GLSLES is available if your GLES implementation reports that it supports OES_texture_3D extension. Read here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_3D.txt It states what new functions are available in GLSLES (texture3D and others).

Comment: The list I keep ever to hand may well not be completely up to date but iOS devices did not expose OES_texture_3D when last I checked.