# Accessing multiple textures from fragment shader in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have N textures in my app, which are 2D slices from 3D volumetric data. In the fragment shader, I need to access all of these textures. My understanding is that I can only access bound textures from the shader, which means I am limited by the number of multi-texturing units allowed.

N can vary from 8 to 512, depending on the data. Is there a way to do this without multi-texturing?

The reason for this approach is because 3D texturing is not available on OpenGL ES 2.0. I'd appreciate suggestions on any other way of doing this.

I also considered texture atlases, but I think the maximum single texture dimensions will be a problem.

Comment: Pleas see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9241746/1262542). Basically, the 2D texture slices are aggregated to a texture atlas, and the coordinates are interpreted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. I did consider atlas as mentioned, but the article is very useful.